# Can't get pinch zoom and rotate gestures working on a container in Nativescript

Tags: gestures, nativescript

I've been trying to get an image zoom, pinch and rotate working for a while now based off of this github project: https://github.com/vakrilov/native-script-pan-scale-demo/blob/master/app/main-page.js . But I can't quite get the trigonometry right. Also I'm unsure why there needs to be a translation during the onPinch method.

```
//initial touch during onPinch method
//args has the touch positions and item is the item to scale
if (args.state === 1) {
    var newOriginX = args.getFocusX() - item.translateX;
    var newOriginY = args.getFocusY() - item.translateY;

    var oldOriginX = item.originX * item.width;
    var oldOriginY = item.originY * item.height;

    item.translateX += (oldOriginX - newOriginX) * (1 - item.scaleX);
    item.translateY += (oldOriginY - newOriginY) * (1 - item.scaleY);

    item.originX = newOriginX / item.width;
    item.originY = newOriginY / item.height;

    startScale = item.scaleX;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

instead of using `item.width` and `item.height`, you should use `item.getMeasuredWidth()` and `item.getMeasuredHeight()`